# Como guardar datos de varios combobox en una lista python

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for, combobox

tengo un problema con esta parte de mi código, estoy haciendo un sistema que guarde datos de cilindros de gas domésticos, primero se pide cuantos cilindros se van a almacenar y después se procede a seleccionar las características de los cilindros con combobox, y aqui es donde esta el error, los datos no se muestran por consola, este es el código:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Toplevel, getint, ttk

ventana = Tk()

def ejecucion():
    can = cantidad.get() +1
    ventana2 = Toplevel()

def guardar():
    print(lista) #SE GUARDARAN LOS DATOS DE LAS LISTAS EN LA BASE DE DATOS 

def imprimir():
    empresa.get()
    tamano.get()
    pico.get()
    

for cilindros in range(1, can ,1):

    titulo = LabelFrame(ventana2, text= f"Cilindro {cilindros}")
    titulo.pack()



    empresa = ttk.Combobox(titulo, values=["Radelco", "PacoGas", "Comunal"])
    empresa.bind("<<ComboboxSelect>>", imprimir)
    empresa.pack()

    tamano = ttk.Combobox(titulo, values=["Pequena", "Mediana", "Regular", "Grande"])
    tamano.bind("<<ComboboxSelect>>", imprimir)
    tamano.pack()

    pico = ttk.Combobox(titulo, values=["Pequeno", "Mediano", "Grande"])
    pico.bind("<<ComboboxSelect>>", imprimir)
    pico.pack()

    lista.append(imprimir)

Button(ventana2, text="Guardar", command=guardar).pack()


lista = []
cantidad = IntVar()

Label(ventana, text="cantidad cilindros").pack()
Entry(ventana, textvariable=cantidad).pack()
Button(ventana, text="listo", command=ejecucion).pack()

ventana.mainloop()
```

Al final esos datos obtenidos se almacenaran a una base de datos, Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Eso se debe a que no estás mandando los datos a imprimir. Envolvé cada intento de imprimir el dato en consola con la función print. Ejemplo: print(empresa.get())

Comment: Si pero quiero que se impriman todo en una lista

edit: probé así y tampoco funciono

Comment: Entonces, creá una lista e imprimila con print. Por otro lado, es raro que print no haga nada, estoy viendo que a tu funcion imprimir le falta aceptar el argumento event: def imprimir(event). Quiza sea por eso que no funciona. Quizas sys.stdout está redireccionado. Usas alguna herramienta de logging, algun editor especial?

Answer (score -1):

Este es un ejemplo muy rapido, espero puedas usarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

un ejercicio rapido.

Comment: 1. El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. 2. ¿Cómo responde este código a la pregunta? Lee [answer] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorarla. Las respuestas no deben ser meramente código: puede que sepas qué hace el mismo, pero otros que lleguen a tener un inconveniente similar, no. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.